# External google login process with .NET Core identity does not save the cookie in the same http request

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, google-oauth, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity

I log in to Google external with .NET identity.

It logs in with Gmail, but it does not save the cookie in the same http request.

So `Redirect(ReturnUrl);` - I direct it to `/home/index`, where I need to save the cookie and access the claims.

However, after `home/index` is fully loaded, it saves my cookie, then after refreshing the page, the claims appear.

There is a layout arrangement according to `isAuthenticated`. When I log in for the first time, it looks like I couldn't log in. However, when I refresh the page, the claims come then because the cookie is saved after `/Home/Index` is completely loaded.

[Reference 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmLYL.png)

[Reference 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Eoa.png)

In the other internal login, as soon as it is directed to `/home/index` from the login method, the cookie is saved and I access the claims. Thus, when the page is loaded, it appears according to `isAuthenticated`.

Do you have any ideas about this? Thanks for everything.

Comment: that sounds like a cookie problem, i blogged about cookie problems here https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I found the problem yesterday and you already mentioned it in your article. Actually, the problem is right in front of my eyes, but I never thought of it. If `SameSite = SameSiteMode.Strict` the cookie will not be saved in the first http request because the request is coming from a 3rd party application.

but if `SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax` there will be no such problem.
Thanks again for your help.